# Counting characters read from a file

Tags: c++, while-loop

This program is meant to read the total characters from a file and output them in another file. Right now it seems to add all the characters, but it also adds the number of extra lines on the file as well, not counting the first line. So if the input file has 10 characters in 4 lines, it should output 40, however it outputs 43.

```
while(getline(in_file,line)){
        
        totChar += line.length();
        
        for(int n = 0; n < line.length(); n++){
            if(line.at(n) == ' '){
                totChar--;
            }
        }
    }
    in_file.close();
```

Comment: It's worth being more specific in your criteria, as `\n` very much is a character.

Comment: Search your favorite C++ reference for `tellg()`.

Comment: As @sweenish hints, characters you don't "see" still count.

Comment: The above explains getting a lower count, but the asker is receiving a higher count. Consider reading the line and placing it in a `std::istringstream`. You can then parse the `istrignstream` with `>>` and it will discard all of the different types of whitespace, not just spaces.

Answer (score 1):

In some systems (such as Windows OS) the line end is made of two octets. `\r\n`. In some systems (such as Linux) the line end is just one octet. `\n`.

`getline()` is expected to discard line-end octet[s] suitable for system it is running on. In the case a text editor on a windows system composed the file and it is parsed on a linux system, `getline()` will discard `\n` but `\r` will remain in the `line` buffer.

Comment: In such a case the \r\n should be automatically translated... Unless you mean a text file intended for a Windows-based system being read on a system expecting a single character line delimiter. If this is the case, you should edit the answer and make this explicit.

Comment: "*In such a case the \r\n should be automatically translated...*" - only if the code were running on Windows. If the code were running on Linux, for instance, but was reading in a Windows-style text file with `\r\n` line breaks, then `\r` would not be discarded.